# HF propagation prediction using machine learning

Tags: hf, propagation, software

Anyone out there know of or developed s/w to predict HF conditions using ML?

Comment: Welcome to ham.stackexchange.com!

Comment: When you say "prediction" do you mean nowcasting, or predicting more than an hour or so into the future?

Comment: Sounds like a good idea for a tech startup.

Comment: Is this specifically about HF propagation, or are you more technically interested on ML-based estimation of RF propagation?

Comment: ML requires training data.  What potential or existing large HF propagation data set is possible to exploit for ML?

Comment: @hotpaw2 amateur contact databases?